# How do I make a mini-panel pane a title?

Tags: 7, panels

I've been replicating some work, in mini-panels, that's already on my site. On one of the mini-panels there is a custom-content pane that is acting as a header. In the gear icon drop down there is a little option called 'Panel Title' that can be selected.

[image]

However, I cannot find this option for other custom panel panes I create.

The content of the already-made title page is simply a Title input.

Would anyone know how I can create this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found it.

It wasn't in the pane settings as I thought (I was looking through loads of Panel documentation). Right at the top of the Edit Mini Panel page there is a dropdown menu called Title Type. You can set this to 'From Pane'.